# Linux: Have terminal run on startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I would like to have the terminal window open when I start my computer.

I think the above is simple, but then I would like it to either load full screen on my second monitor, or I would like it to run on the right third of my main monitor. If I maximize another window on my main monitor I would like it to not full screen over the terminal but instead fill up the remaining 2/3's of the screen.

Anyone know any programs or approach to try and set this up?

Comment: This Ask Ubuntu question may be of interest: http://askubuntu.com/questions/107951/how-to-set-a-specific-window-size-for-all-windows-that-open-to-default

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of your question, you can execute terminal in full screen using following command:

```
gnome-terminal --full-screen
```

If you want it to be specific size or on specific display, you can use:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=GEOMETRY
```

From gnome-terminal help, geometry: Set the window size; for example: 80x24, or 80x24+200+200 (COLSxROWS+X+Y)

To show it on specific display, you can use:

```
gnome-terminal --display=DISPLAY
```

About second part of your question, one way to achieve this you might need to use tiling window manager like http://awesome.naquadah.org/